# codeigniter group_by returning only first row

Tags: codeigniter, group-by

i have this problem in codeigniter:
I try to make a navigation tree system from database.

model:

```
function getServices()
{
 $this->db->select('service_url, service_title, category_title');    
 $this->db->join('services_category', 'services_category.id=services.category_id');    
 $this->db->group_by('category_title');
 $this->db->order_by('service_title', 'ASC');    
 $query = $this->db->get('services');

 if($query->result() == TRUE)    
 {    
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
       $result[] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
  }
}
```

view:

```
<?php if(isset($services) && $services) : foreach($services as $s) : ?>    
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><?php echo $s['category_title'] ?></a>    
       <ul>
        <li><?php echo anchor('services/' . $s['service_url'], $s['service_title']); ?></li>
       </ul>    
     </li>    
   </ul>    
<?php endforeach; ?>    
<?php endif; ?>
```

now so far so good, the result is returning each category the way is supposed to, but the service is returning only one service per category, and in some categories there is like 15 services.
Anybody kind to give me a hand, or an explanation what is going wrong ?
Thank you so much.

"i'm not an expert in php or codeigniter, i just started not long time ago, so please don't shoot the beginner."

note: i tried without the group_by and order_by, and is returning all services, but the categories are repeating,

ex:

```
category-a
   service1
category-a
   service2
category-b
   service10
category-b
   service11
category-c
   service30
category-c
  service31
....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good read for aggregate functions when using [Group By (MySQL)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).
A simple explanation would be like this

```
Date        | Amount
2012-01-01  | 5
2012-01-01  | 6
2012-01-02  | 1
2012-01-02  | 6
```

Now using SUM aggregate function like this.

```
SELECT Date, SUM(Amount) as Total FROM table GROUP BY Date ORDER BY DATE;
```

The result will be:

```
Date        | Amount
2012-01-01  | 11
2012-01-02  | 7
```

In your scenario, `GROUP BY` will not work as intended as it will only get one Category since you grouped your query by each category.

The ideal solution to this is to have 2 separate functions, `GetCategories` and `GetServices`.

```
function getServices($category_id = false)
{
  $this->db->select('service_url, service_title, category_title');
  $this->db->join('services_category', 'services_category.id=services.category_id');
  if ($category_id !== false)
    $this->db->where('services.category_id', $category_id);
  $this->db->order_by('service_title', 'ASC');
  $query = $this->db->get('services');

  if($query->result() == TRUE)
  {
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
      $result[] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
  }
}

function getCategories()
{
  $this->db->select('category_id, category_title');
  $this->db->order_by('category_title', 'ASC');
  $query = $this->db->get('services_category');

  if($query->result() == TRUE)
  {
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
      $result[] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
  }
}
```

Then in your view file, you just need to do a for loop on the Categories then do another query for each Category. Here's an outline of what it will look like,

```
<?php if(isset($categories) && $categories) : foreach($categories as $category) : ?>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><?php echo $category['category_title'] ?></a>
      <ul>
        // how you get $services is similar to how you get $categories
        <?php $services = $this->modelname->getServices($category['category_id']);
        <?php foreach($services as $s) : ?>
          <li><?php echo anchor('categories/' . $s['service_url'], $s['service_title']); ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: man, you are a legend, i swear on god i was looking for this over 4hours and no answer, definitely i will write a tutorial about this on blog, and of course i will mention you.Thank you so much, i really appreciate your help

Comment: actually i want to ask you something if is not too much, is it good practice to use the model in the view? doesn't break the MVC ?

Comment: Hi Alex, it doesn't break MVC since you still maintained your data definition in the model, you just exposed the model's methods in your view, which ideally should be at the controller level. I usually use helpers so all calls to the model from both controllers/views are in the helpers.