# order by along with group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('messages');
$this->db->where('user_id_get', $data['users_id']);
$this->db->group_by('user_id_get');
//$this->db->order_by('id','DESC'); This doesn't work
$data["Query"] = $this->db->get();
```

how can i use order_by along with group_by here in my query(codeigniter)?

Comment: Refer below link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943388/codeigniter-group-by-with-order-by-not-working-as-expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943388/codeigniter-group-by-with-order-by-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Ok, but what is it in my query?

Comment: ID is not in your group by how can it order by it??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not to familiar with sql treatment in codeigniter, but what does `groupBy user_id_get` together with a `select *` mean?

If several rows with the same `user_id_get`-value get aggregated and represented by only one of them, what value do other attributes than `user_id_get` have then? Actually, only one of the grouped records can be taken, some DB systems take the first, other DB systems (and SQL standard) even prohibit the use of other attributes than those referred to in the group by clause. Confer, for example, this [discussion at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12926064/2630032).

Consequently, if only one of the records of a group is taken, what does it then mean to sort on an attribute other than the group-by attribute, as this would mean to sort on probably randomly selected values, right?

So if you want to get all messages of a particular user (as expression `where('user_id_get', $data['users_id']` indicates), then `group by user_id_get` is misleading; I'd omit the group by and use only the order by.

Hope I understand your requirements right and hope it helps.